# How does process migration work in Meterpreter

Tags: windows, meterpreter

Did anyone try to figure out how process migration works in Meterpreter in Windows? I want to make my own script to learn that, but am failing to find a starting point for that. Well, I have an idea to use `NtQuerySystemInformation` library and its `SystemHandleInformation` function, as it can return handle of a thread in the OS and using those I can change its parent, but I doubt that it's going to work (due to TEB). And I have a feeling that there should be an easier way than `NtQuerySystemInformation`. Could anyone suggest a DLL or an algorithm to use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how migrate works in meterpreter:

1. Get the PID the user wants to migrate into. This is the target
   process.
2. Check the architecture of the target process whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit. It is important for memory alignment.
3. Check if the meterpreter process has the SeDebugPrivilege. This is
   used to get a handle to the target process. Further details at
       http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131065
4. Get the actual payload from
       the handler that is going to be injected into the target process.
       Calculate its length as well.
5. Call the OpenProcess() API to gain
       access to the virtual memory of the target process.
6. Call the
       VirtualAllocEx() API to allocate an RWX (Read, Write, Execute)
       memory in the target process
7. Call the WriteProcessMemory() API to
       write the payload in the target memory virtual memory space.
8. Call
       the CreateRemoteThread() API to execute the newly created memory
       stub having the injected payload in a new thread.
9. Shutdown the
       previous thread having the initial meterpreter running in the old
       process.

Comment: This is pretty much spot on. The only thing that's worth mentioning on top of this is that there's a little bit of magic required to make it possible to run code in x64 processes from x86 processes.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in the [deepest places](https://github.com/psychomario/pyinject/blob/master/dllinject.py) of github I've found this code which does all the necessary stuff, so those who look for this info can find an answer in the below API functions:

```
def injectshellcode(self, shellcode):
    """This function merely executes what it is given"""
    shellcodeaddress = self.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(
                                                    self.handle,
                                                    None,
                                                    len(shellcode),
                                                    0x1000,
                                                    0x40
                                                    )
    self.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(
                                    self.handle,
                                    shellcodeaddress,
                                    shellcode,
                                    len(shellcode),
                                    None
                                    )
    thread = self.kernel32.CreateRemoteThread(
                                    self.handle,
                                    None,
                                    0,
                                    shellcodeaddress,
                                    None,
                                    0,
                                    None
                                    )
```

Comment: metasploit is also on Github - you might find the specific migration code for the meterpreter there