# How exactly do "hidden" processes work

Tags: metasploit, process

How can a process be hidden inside another one?

Is the process moved into another process and turned into a thread with it's own run loop?

How exactly does a process get moved? I see this Metasploit command, `migrate PID` which seems to do this.

I would like to know how this works internally, does it use IPC or if the memory of the process is being moved into a target process with PID, how is this done and how does the process being migrated continue to run?

Comment: Process migration in metasploit has been explained here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90578/how-does-process-migration-work-in-meterpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the process moved into another process and turned into a thread with it's own run loop?

Essentially Yes.