# Manually migrate to another process without using metasploit?

Tags: metasploit, shellcode, meterpreter

There is a useful meterpreter script that allows to migrate meterpreter to another process by specifying its PID.
Imagine I have my own session running. How could I migrate to another process without using metasploit?
I know the question may sound vague. Even if you don't provide a complete answer but still give some pointers, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction The answer there clearly states how this is performed in Metasploit, so the OP can replicate the process *without* using metasploit.

Answer (score 0):

There was recently a [similar question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90578/how-does-process-migration-work-in-meterpreter) here. The answer describes in a couple of steps how it works. In a second answer there is even a python example. I guess this also works relatively well with powershell - provided enough powershell programming expertise.

Comment: Thank you. The API calls in the answer make sense. I got how it work now. I was wondering if it used another way or not.